# Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7146491840906359738 bytes)

Tags: php, functions, memory

We're on v4.4.10 and keep having to restart the web server due to this issue.  I've read various other posts and increased the wp-config.php memory, but still get this error.

[23-May-2017 11:39:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7146491840906359738 bytes) in D:\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4886

Line 4886  function is:

```
function wp_is_stream( $path ) {
    $wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();
    $wrappers_re = '(' . join('|', $wrappers) . ')';

    return preg_match( "!^$wrappers_re://!", $path ) === 1;
}
```

Is there a way to test for the current length and if it's over a certain amount do something with it?

Comment: I can only imagine that a plugin or other script is calling stream_wrapper_register() far, far too often.

Comment: After reading https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72451 it looks like an Apache issue. You might want to update your question with your exact platform details. Odds are that this is not WordPress or PHP.

Answer (score 7):

Ater months of searching I stubmled upon this

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72451

The bug is resolved in PHP 7.1.

Comment: You should probably have added this as a comment rather than an answer.